# Faye unsubscribe not triggering anything on the server

Tags: node.js, faye

I have a very simple Faye server running in node.js that looks like this:

```
faye.on('subscribe', function(message, channel) {
    console.log('subscribed', channel);
}
faye.on('unsubscribe', function(message, channel) {
    console.log('unsubscribed',channel);
}
```

In my client i am doing the following:

```
f = new Faye.Client(url);
var s = f.subscribe('/test'); // The server hits the subscribe event
s.cancel();  // Nothing happens on the server
f.unsubscribe('/test');  // Nothing happens here either
```

It was my understanding that doing either of these unsubscribe methods should trigger a message to /meta/unsubscribe and the server should see the 'unsubscribe' event, but it seems that is not the case here. I have even tried adding an incoming extension on the server and even still, never once do I see an anything incoming where message.channel === '/meta/unsubscribe'

Can anyone shed some light on why I'm not seeing the unsub events fire?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working faye server example (notice the bayeux):

```
'use strict'

var server = function(port, pathOptional){
    var http = require('http'),
        faye = require('faye');

    var server = http.createServer();
    var path = '';
    if (pathOptional){
        path += pathOptional;
    }
    var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/'+path});

    bayeux.on('subscribe', function(message, channel) {
        console.log('subscribed', channel, message);
    });
    bayeux.on('unsubscribe', function(message, channel) {
        console.log('unsubscribed',channel);
    });
    bayeux.attach(server);
    server.listen(port);
    console.log('server listening on port '+port.toString() );

}


server(8002);
```